# How do I install Manajro KDE Theme, Manjaro GNOME Theme and Manjaro's icon pack in Arch Linux KDE?

Tags: arch-linux, kde, manjaro, theme, plasma5

How do I install Manajro KDE Theme, Manjaro GNOME Theme and Manjaro's icon pack in Arch Linux KDE? Because I really like their themes and icons and I dont want to distrohop just for that! Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you run KDE, as your tags include KDE.

1. Make sure yay (or any other AUR helper) is installed
2. Install `breath2-git` (`yay install breath2-git` for yay) This should include the icon theme, a wallpaper, the login screen (SDDM) theme and the Manjaro Plasma theme (I think it's a global theme selectable from System settings)
3. The earlier package should have `breath-gtk-theme` as an optional dependency, so I think it'll get installed in the earlier package. Just to be sure, I'll include that you can install the GNOME (GTK) theme by `yay install breath-gtk-theme` if it does not get automatically installed.

Just to clarify, the KDE Plasma desktop has multiple themes that construct the desktop look and feel.

The icon theme is included in `breath2-git`.

What you call a "GNOME theme" is usually called a "GTK theme". The GTK theme is included as an optional dependency in `breath2-git`, and can by explicitly installed from `breath-gtk-theme` if not installed through the earlier package.

What you call a "KDE theme" can mean many things, including a Qt theme, (controls the look of buttons, containers, etc in applications) a color theme, (controls colors of applications and (I think) the widgets) a Plasma theme (controls the look of widgets including panels, the desktop, etc) and whatever I forgot to mention. `breath2-git` should included all those.

Ask me anything if you need more info.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to install the Breathe Qt and GTK theme. Well actually its not yay install, but yay -S. But thanks again!

Comment: @AnujTambe I think yay install works too, they might be some kind of aliases or something as some guides on the internet show people using yay install and I've always done yay install instead of yay -S

Comment: Ok, might be! But yay install tells no package match search.

Comment: Ok, maybe there is a difference, anyways, glad you got it working.